# Parse enormous json file, output objects to their own files

Tags: json, jq

I have json files of arbitrary size, some small, some enormous (>40GB).  I'm trying to use `jq` to stream objects from an `object_array` to their own files for later processing.

`object_array` has `N` objects.

The json has the following structure:

```
{
    "top_level_name": "Some Name Here",
    "top_level_type": "Some Type",
    "last_updated_on": "2022-07-09",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "object_array": [
        {
            "arrangement": "abcd",
            "name": "another name",
            "type": "efgh",
            "type_ver": "2021",
            "code": "12345",
            "desc": "some description",
            "rate": [
                {
                    "groups": [
                        {
                            "IDs": [
                                "123654890",
                                "012365485"
                            ],
                            "id_type": {
                                "type": "xyz",
                                "value": "8527419630"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "prices": [
                        {
                            "price_type": "priceType",
                            "rate": "00.00",
                            "date": "2023-01-01",
                            "svc_code": [
                                "89"
                            ],
                            "class": "some-class",
                            "modifier": [
                                "78"
                            ],
                            "additional_information": "null"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The current path I'm on has me trying `jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))' test.json| awk '{print > "onif00" NR ".json"}'` but my results vary from a single file with all the data or a ton of files each with some piece of the data e.g. `[` followed by another file with `{` etc.

Specifically, I'd like to capture each object like the one below, from `object_array`, and place it in its own file

```
{
    "arrangement": "abcd",
    "name": "another name",
    "type": "efgh",
    "type_ver": "2021",
    "code": "12345",
    "desc": "some description",
    "rate": [{
        "groups": [{
            "IDs": [
                "123654890",
                "012365485"
            ],
            "id_type": {
                "type": "xyz",
                "value": "8527419630"
            }
        }],
        "prices": [{
            "price_type": "priceType",
            "rate": "00.00",
            "date": "2023-01-01",
            "svc_code": [
                "89"
            ],
            "class": "some-class",
            "modifier": [
                "78"
            ],
            "additional_information": "null"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Good first Q in that you have provided small sample data! But include you best attempt at `maybe-create-files-with-awk` so people can help correct your thinking (-;! ++ for formatting your data! Good luck!

Comment: Could you provide a better example for your input? It looks like you posted a badly formatted json snippet. And if you were to stream that input, it's precise structure matters. Is your input an array of that object or just that object alone?

Comment: @JeffMercado, that structure is exactly how the source is -- the only difference is key names and values have been changed.  I ran it through https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ after editing to ensure it I didn't accidentally break the formatting.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. What should each smaller file contain precisely? It would be helpful to show simpler input and the actual output.

Comment: The way you had the json formatted in the question made it appear like there were mismatched closing braces just floating there. Cleaned it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

As in the Q, I'd avoid calling jq more than once.  I also like using awk, so if for example you want .name as part of the file name, I'd go with s.t. like:

```
< my.json jq -cnr --stream '
    fromstream(2|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "object_array")) )
    | .name, .
' | awk 'fn=="" {fn=$1; next} {print > "onif00_" fn ".json"; fn=""; }'
```

---

This has also been tested using gojq, the Go implementation of jq.

See @Jeff_Mercado's comment elsewhere on this page re adapting this for versions of jq which support --stream but for which `fromstream` is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Apart from jq, this is a pure `bash` solution. For an `awk` solution, see @peak's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73738779/2158479).

In jq, `select` from the stream those parts that belong to the `object_array`, then truncate by `2` (field name and array index).
In the shell, `read` the lines provided by `jq -c` and redirect them to a file.

```bash
< enormous.json jq -cn --stream '
  fromstream(2|truncate_stream(inputs| select(.[0][0] == "object_array")))
' | while read -r json;
    do fname="onif00$((++NR))"; > "$fname.json" cat <<< "$json";
    done
```

To also extract data to be used for naming the files, interleavingly output them as well. To allow for any string, including special characters such as newlines (although you shouldn't use newlines in file names), change the line delimiter to the `NUL` byte (using `-j` and `"\u0000"` in jq, and `-d ''` with read). For instance, taking the `.name` value from the sample input and appending `.json` results in a file called `another name.json`.

```bash
< enormous.json jq -jn --stream '
  fromstream(2|truncate_stream(inputs| select(.[0][0] == "object_array")))
  | (.name, @json) + "\u0000"
' | while read -d '' fname; read -d '' json;
    do > "$fname.json" cat <<< "$json";
    done
```

---

Note: Apparently, for jq versions prior to 1.6 there was a bug in `truncate_stream/1` that prevented it from taking inputs other than `1`. One remedy would be to redefine `truncate_stream` yourself by prepending your filter with

```bash
def truncate_stream(stream):
  . as $n | null | stream | . as $input
  | if (.[0]|length) > $n then setpath([0];$input[0][$n:]) else empty end;
```

This was taken directly from the [1.6 source code](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/jq-1.6/src/builtin.jq#L217-L218), and it works perfectly with jq 1.5, for example.

Comment: Just make sure you're using jq 1.6 or higher, there was a bug in `truncate_stream/1` that prevented it from taking inputs other than `1`.

Comment: @JeffMercado Oh, I didn't know that! For those using jq < 1.6: Just redefine `truncate_stream` by prepending your filter with `def truncate_stream(stream): . as $n | null | stream | . as $input | if (.[0]|length) > $n then setpath([0];$input[0][$n:]) else empty end;`. This is taken from the [1.6 source code](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/jq-1.6/src/builtin.jq#L217-L218) but it also works perfectly with jq 1.5, for example.